# Test which one of two (mechanistic / non-regression) models fits the observations better

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, model-comparison

There's a large number of similar questions, but they mostly seem to be about regression models and deal with cross validation, comparison of nested statistical models via likelihood-ratio, etc. Apologies if these methods are applicable and I just don't realize how.

**Problem:** I want to compare two relatively complex simulation models which predict a time-series and test which one fits the observations better. *No parameters are being fitted.* These are not regression models.

I'd like to say whether or not the accuracy of the two models is significantly different, so a simple comparison of RMSEs isn't enough.

**Example:** Let's say I want to test which one of two numerical weather prediction models is better at predicting the temperature at place X (where I have a thermometer). Both models are mostly identical and rely on the same input variables, except for one process, which is modelled in a fundamentally different way (i.e. this is not just about adding a single parameter).

What kind of test would be suitable for this? I'm thinking about testing for differences in the residuals, but I'm not sure in what way exactly (i.e. do I test for differences in the residuals and just check which distribution is closer to zero? Do I compare absolute or squared residuals with a KS-Test? If yes, which one?). Or is there a simpler solution?

(Bonus: In my specific problem I have a strong suspicion which of the two models is more accurate, so a one-sided variant would be interesting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that running statistical tests/fitted statistical models on the residuals is the right way to go.

**Bias**: which set of residuals has a mean closer to zero? Use a t-test: You probably want to use the Welch/Satterthwaite version that allows for the possibility that the variances are different in each group.  t-tests are fairly robust to non-Normality (e.g. see answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/robust-t-test-for-mean)).

**Variance**: [Levene's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test) or Levene's median test (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57323/comparison-of-p-values-for-levene-mean-test-and-levene-median-test)).

**RMSE**: I'm not sure, but any sensible procedure to test the difference in locations (means/medians) of the distribution of squared errors (which incorporate both variance and bias) [t-test, Mann-Whitney, etc.].

More parametrically, you could fit a generalized least-squares model that allowed for changes in mean and variance of residuals across groups. In R's `nlme` package that would be something like

```
gls(resid ~ resid_type, weights=varIdent(form=~1|resid_type), data=...)
```

This would also allow you to ask deeper/more interesting questions, e.g. whether the bias and variance vary across the data set (e.g. bias or variance change with temperature, or with other covariates).

A Kolmogorov-Smirnov test will just test whether the residuals are **different**, which doesn't seem like it will be very interesting ...